# Radio buttons updating a database deletes the entry?

Tags: php, html

so I'm creating a small form where you can update the values of some fields pulled from a database.

Two of the fields I have however are acting wrong, when the page loads they display the information correctly but when you press 'submit' the fields in the MySQL table go blank. All the other fields update correctly including a checkbox, but not these two radio buttons.

Here's the code for it, I'm sorry to be asking this but does anyone see the error? I'm rather new with PHP so I'm not sure what to look for.

Snippet of the PHP Code (I can post the full code of it, but it's long):

```
<?php 

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  $mbr=$_POST['mbr'];
  $rec=$_POST['rec']; 

  $update = $dbconnect->query("UPDATE testing SET mbr='$mbr', rec='$rec'");
  } 

  ?>
```

HTML Code for the 2 radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="mbr" <?php echo $upChecked; ?>>Up <input type="radio" name="mbr" <?php echo $downChecked; ?>>Down

<input type="radio" name="rec" <?php echo $yesChecked; ?>>Yes <input type="radio" name="rec" <?php echo $noChecked; ?>>No
```

Comment: 1. Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. 2. Print out your query and make sure the `$_POST` vars are what you expect them to be. 3. That query updates all rows in the database. 4. Chances are it's lacking `value` attributes on the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I'm dumb and tired and missed the obvious solution, I forgot to put the values of the buttons in their code.

How they should be

```
<input type="radio" name="mbr" value="up" <?php echo $upChecked; ?>>Up <input type="radio" name="mbr" value="down" <?php echo $downChecked; ?>>Down
<input type="radio" name="rec" value="yes" <?php echo $yesChecked; ?>>Yes <input type="radio" name="rec" value="no" <?php echo $noChecked; ?>>
```